# playlist de audio no funciona con .MP3 local

Tags: javascript, audio, href

Tengo una función de playlist con javascript que funciona muy bien con la lista de audio online.

Si la lista con la etiqueta `a` es de dirección tipo HTTPS://, funciona muy bien.

[Éste el original que funciona bien](https://www.google.com/amp/s/ricardogeek.com/como-crear-un-playlist-de-audio-con-javascript/%3Famp) (con URL en la web).

Pero cuando el `href` de la etiqueta `a` es local de tipo **../lista/audio.mp3**, (o parecido) el siguiente track no se reproduce.
Solamente se reproduce al seleccionar con `click`.

No estoy seguro de porque no funciona el playlist con una dirección local en el `href` de la lista en HTML5

```js
init();

function init() { 

var audio = document.getElementById("audio"); 
var playlist = document.getElementById('playlist'); 
var tracks = playlist.getElementsByTagName('a'); 

audio.volume = 0.10; 
audio.play(); 

for(var track in tracks) { 
    
    var link = tracks[track]; 
    
    if(typeof link === "function" || typeof link === "number") continue;            
    
    link.addEventListener("click", function(e) {    
        
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var song = this.getAttribute('href');   
        
        run(song, audio, this); 
    }); 

} 

audio.addEventListener("ended", function(e) { 
    
    for(var track in tracks) {
        
        var link = tracks[track]; 
        var nextTrack = parseInt(track) + 1;    
        
        if(typeof link === "function" || typeof link === "number") continue; 
        
        if(!this.src) this.src = tracks[0]; 
        
        if(track == (tracks.length - 1)) nextTrack = 0; 
        
        console.log(nextTrack);     
        
        if(link.getAttribute("href") === this.src) {    
            
            var nextLink = tracks[nextTrack];   
            run(nextLink.getAttribute('href'), audio, nextLink); 
            break; 
        
        } 
    
    } 

}); 

} 

function run(song, audio, link) { 

var parent = link.parentElement;

//quitar el active de todos los elementos de la lista   
var items = parent.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('li'); 

for(var item in items) { 
    if(items[item].classList) items[item].classList.remove("active"); 
} 

//agregar active a este elemento 
parent.classList.add("active"); 

//tocar la cancion 
audio.src = song; 
audio.load(); 
audio.play(); 
}
```

```css
audio {
display: block;
width: 100%;
max-width: 300px;
}

#playlist {
display: block;
width: 100%;
max-width: 300px;
padding: 10px 5px;
list-style: none;
}

a { 
text-decoration: none; 
} 

.active a { 
color: #5DB0E6; 
text-decoration: none; 
} 

li a {
color: #eeeedd; 
background: #333; 
padding: 5px; 
display: block; 
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" > 
  <source src="../audio/uno.mp3"> 
</audio>
    
    <ul id="playlist"> 
        
        <li class="active"> 
            <a href="../audio/uno.mp3">Audio uno</a> 
        </li> 
        
        <li>
            <a href="../audio/dos.mp3">Audio dos</a> 
        </li> 
        
        
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias cosas a corregir en tu código:

- En general, evita declarar variables con `var`, porque se declaran en ámbito global y pueden interferir en otras partes de tu código. Te recomiendo leer [este artículo](https://cybmeta.com/var-let-y-const-en-javascript) para saber más al respecto
- Hay algunas condicionales que no tienen sentido, porque obtienes elementos HTML y comparas si son función o número
- Al buscar la canción que se está reproduciendo, dentro del ciclo, deberías tener solo la comparación y, en caso de coincidencia, establecer el valor de `nextTrack` y salir del ciclo con `break`, pero el método [.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) facilita esa labor
- Te recomiendo usar [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) en lugar de obtener elementos por clase o etiqueta, creo que es más sencillo y, además, se puede iterar más fácilmente con `.forEach()`, aunque debes tener en cuenta que esto es más una cuestión de preferencia que de optimización

```js
let audio = document.getElementById("audio"); 
let playlist = document.getElementById('playlist');
// querySelectorAll devuelve una lista de nodos iterable
let tracks = playlist.querySelectorAll('a'); 

audio.volume = 0.10; 
audio.play(); 

init();

function init() {
    // Recorrer con forEach
    tracks.forEach(function(track) { 
        track.addEventListener("click", function(e) {    
            e.preventDefault(); 
            let song = this.getAttribute('href');   
            run(song, audio, this); 
        }); 
    });
    
    // Asignar evento a audio
    audio.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
        // Obtener índice de audio actual
        let index = Array.from(tracks).getIndex(track => track.href == audio.src);
        // Saber si se está encontrando, si se obtiene -1 quiere decir que no
        console.log(index);
        // Incrementar índice
        index ++;
        // Si se llegó al final
        if(index >= tracks.length) {
            // Reinicar la lista, volviendo a la primera canción
            index = 0;
        }
        // Obtener camción de acuerdo al índice
        let track = tracks[index];
        let song = track.href;
        // Reproducir siguiente canción
        run(song, audio, track);
    });
} 

function run(song, audio, link) { 
    let parent = link.parentElement;

    // Obtener elemento activo
    let item = playlist.querySelector('li.active');
    // Eliminar clase de elemento activo
    item.classList.remove('active');

    // Agregar active a siguiente elemento
    parent.classList.add("active"); 

    //tocar la cancion 
    audio.src = song; 
    audio.load(); 
    audio.play(); 
}
```

```css
audio {
display: block;
width: 100%;
max-width: 300px;
}

#playlist {
display: block;
width: 100%;
max-width: 300px;
padding: 10px 5px;
list-style: none;
}

a { 
text-decoration: none; 
} 

.active a { 
color: #5DB0E6; 
text-decoration: none; 
} 

li a {
color: #eeeedd; 
background: #333; 
padding: 5px; 
display: block; 
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" > 
  <source src="../audio/uno.mp3"> 
</audio>
    
    <ul id="playlist"> 
        
        <li class="active"> 
            <a href="../audio/uno.mp3">Audio uno</a> 
        </li> 
        
        <li>
            <a href="../audio/dos.mp3">Audio dos</a> 
        </li> 
        
        
    </ul>
```

**¿Qué pasa si no se encuentra el índice de la canción que se está reproduciendo?**

En ocasiones, el navegador suele agregar protocolo y dominio a las propiedades `href`, `src` y similares, provocando que las comparaciones fallen. De ser el caso, buscas el índice del elemento de lista que tiene la clase activa y lo usas para avanzar la reproducción.

Cambia esta línea:

```
let index = Array.from(tracks).getIndex(track => track.href == audio.src);
```

Por estas dos:

```
let items = playlist.querySelectorAll('li');
let index = Array.from(items).getIndex(item => item.classList.contains('active'));
```

El enlace de audio está en la misma posición del elemento activo.

Comment: Será que hay algún error o falta algo que hace que no funcione ?? Probé varias veces y también en teléfono pero a mí no me funciona

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz, revisa la consola para ver si hay errores

Comment: Estuve probando pero no encuentro la falla. Casi no tengo tengo tiempo, pero voy a analizar bien

Comment: Ice algunos cambios en este código usando el forEach y al final adapte a mi funciones y me funciona.